# Why my function works for matrix but why not for vector?

Tags: julia, matrix-multiplication

I am confused in the term "Duck-Typing". I've Written a function which is applicable for a matrix but why it gets error whenever I tried to use a vector as parameter?

[image: Here's My piece of code that i've written]

Comment: Don't just paste screen shots of your code. Actually copy a minimal example illustrating the problem into the question so we can easily run it ourselves.

Comment: actually, this is my first post .Thanks for the suggestion and answer also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it looks like you are lucking out and there happens to be an implementation of the base exponentiation method (`^`) that is specifically designed for matrices. Probably because matrix powers is commonly useful and I'm willing to bet there are a lot of optimizations for them.

```
@which v1^2
```

> ^(A::AbstractArray{T,2} where T, p::Integer) in LinearAlgebra at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.1\LinearAlgebra\src\dense.jl:366

But there isn't a built-in for vectors. Note that for matrix `A`, `A^2` means `A * A` using matrix multiplication rules, not the same as squaring each element in `A`. For a 2 by 2 matrix `A = [a b; c d]`, you would get:

```
A = [a  b]
    [c  d]
A^2 = [a*a+b*c  a*b+b*d]
      [c*a+d*c  c*b+d*d]
```

For a vector `v`, the equivalent I guess would be `v^2 = v' * v`, the dot product between the transpose of `v` and `v` itself, giving you a scalar (now I'm really wishing I could use LaTeX symbols in SO).

In general, if you want an operator to *broadcast* (be applied to every element of an array or matrix magically), add a dot in front of it.

```
func = v -> println(v.^2)
func(v2)
# [0.0826262, 0.127083, 0.513595]
```

This takes *each element* of `v2 = [a, b, c]` and squares it: `[a^2, b^2, c^2]`. It similarly squares *each element* of `v1` instead of doing the matrix multiplication.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)